# Include events in weekly Newsletter

Tags: feature-request, chat, events

I just got the weekly Mi.Yodeya email (sent out every Tuesday). Why isn't there a reminder for the weekly Parsha Chat event that is every Wednesday? It should be included in the email. Please upvote this proposal and my answer if you would also like it and other chat events to be included in the newsletter email.

Comment: ...and downvote if you want them not to be.

Comment: Did you just invent a new tag?

Comment: [meta-tag:newsletter]? Yes.

Comment: Relevant information from MSO: 1) The [original announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96758) of newsletters indicated that in "v2," mods would be able to insert announcements; this hasn't been implemented yet. 2) [Elections are announced in newsletters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121562). 3) [Snippets of site blog posts are included](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108886). (We don't have a site blog yet.) 4) [Meta questions are not included](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121622), but there's some discussion of including [meta-tag:featured] ones.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - What is MSO?

Comment: @AdamMosheh MSO = http://meta.stackoverflow.com , which includes discussion of Stack-Exchange-network-wide issues, feature requests, etc.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - When is v2?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, your guess is as good as mine. Probably "when they get around to it." I'll bring this post to the attention of SE staff tonight (or one of the other mods can do it now) and see what the plans for newsletter enhancement are.

Comment: Re "When is v2?": http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514

Answer (score 2):

Yes, events such as the Parsha Chat should be included in the weekly emails.

Comment: +1 |||||||||||||||

Answer (score -2):

No, the newsletter should stay the way it is.

Comment: -1 ||||||||||||